# Relative positioning of generated svg objects in D3

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js, svg

Let me start with the context:

I'm using D3 to generate randomized worksheets for my wife's students who are learning their numbers from 11 to 99. It creates columns of 10 circles to represent the tens place, and a single column of 1-9 circles for the units place.

I've been able to successfully build all of the objects I need, and it randomizes on refresh, which is perfect for my needs at this point, but I'm having trouble with alignment.

Here's the (somewhat messy) example: [CodePen - Montessori Number Generator](http://codepen.io/NeversDesign/pen/wWaOvW)

The concept is based on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/kevintcoughlin/JV62X/)

I'd prefer the columns to be centred in the space, but I've not yet been able to get the math to work out for it (I've ended up aligning the tens to the left and the units to the right).

The crucial equation I'm trying to figure out is for the `cx` value on the generated circles.

For the Tens group:

```
var tens = d3.range(10).map(function(r, d) {return {
  radius: 15,
  cx: svgWidth / 2 - r*50 + 9 * (r + 4),
  cy: d * 30 + 72 }})
```

And the `cx` value for the Units is calculated using the width of the Tens group:

```
var w = d3.select('#tens')[0][0].getBBox().width;

for (var j = 0; j < units.length; j++) {
  gUnits.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", ( (svgWidth + w ) / 2 + w/45 ) )
    .attr("cy", units[j].cy)
    .attr("r", units[j].radius)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", 3);
}
```

The example works reasonably well for mid-range numbers (40-60 range), but smaller numbers cause overlap, and larger numbers get pushed off the side of the canvas, and none are actually perfectly centred.

It's also possible that I've gone about this all wrong, and there's a much simpler solution that I'm just not seeing.

If there is, the other big two requirements that I need to meet for my wife is this: there must be some space between the tens group and the units group, and the final number can't be a multiple of 10 (i.e. the units group cannot be zero).

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: So you want to get a random number between 0-99 and  show the number on the left in sections of 10 and what ever is left over on the right ? What are the two lines for ?

Comment: the two lines are for the child to write the numerals for the tens place and units place - they have no actual bearing on the problem at hand

Comment: As much as I love D3, I think I would approach this problem with flexbox. I would have ten divs; nine of them for the "teens," "twenties," "thirties," etc, and one of them for the one's. Then, I would conditionally set those divs to `display: block' or 'display: none' based on the number in question. A similar thing would need be done within the div for the one's column. Flexbox would help you size and space these without needing to figure out specific coordinates. Just brainstorming here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

```
//generate a number between 11 and 99 
var  randNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 90 + 11)

//Get difference when divide rand number by 10
var circleUnits = Math.round(randNumber%10);

//get how many 10's you can fit in what is left over
var circleTens = Math.round(randNumber-circleUnits)/10 ;

//use this data to generate arrays to work with
var circleUnitsData = d3.range(circleUnits).map(function(j, i) {return {
count : i,
    radius: 15
}})

var circleTensData = d3.range(circleTens).map(function(j, i) {return {
count : i+1,
    radius: 15
}})
```

Here is how I generated the circles for the tens. Because there are always going to be 10 circles in each column (that's why I divided it by 10 above) :

```
 var nodeRadius = 15;
 var tensContainer = gTens.selectAll('circle') //put this outside the foreach so you don't overwrite any other circles
 var difference = 5; //gap between circles

circleTensData.forEach(function(d ,i){
tensContainer.data([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr("cx",function(e,j) {
//  console.log(e)
  return 100 +  i * nodeRadius*2 + (i*difference) //use i here to get what set of 10 it is in
}) 
  .attr("cy", function(e,j) {
  return 100 +  j * nodeRadius*2  + (j*difference) //use j here to increment downwards 
})
  .attr("r", function(e) {
  return nodeRadius //hard coded radius above
}) 
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("stroke-width", 3);
})
```

Then the units are even easier. To work out the x position I multiplied the size of the 10's dataset by the width of the node plus the difference and added 40 to give it an offset. So every time you refresh, the units are 40 units to the right :

```
 var circlesUnits = gUnits.selectAll('circle')
   .data(circleUnitsData)
   .enter()
   .append('circle')
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
    var i = circleTensData.length;
    console.log(400 +  i * nodeRadius*2 + (i*difference))
     return 140 +  i * nodeRadius*2 + (i*difference)
   })
   .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
     return 100 +  i * nodeRadius*2  + (i *difference)
   })
   .attr("r", function(d) {
     return d.radius
   }) 
   .attr("fill", "white")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("stroke-width", 3);
```

On refresh I added an alert to show you the random number.

If I have misread the question, or have any questions, please feel free to comment and I will adjust. Hopefully this helps you out :)

Update fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/8hc0sfbg/1/

EDIT

You say you don't want the number to end in 0. The following will work :

```
function getRand() {

  var randNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * 90 + 11) // number between 0-99
  if (randNumber % 10 == 0) { //if ends in 0 run again
    return getRand();
  }
  return randNumber;
}
```

I have wrapped the code in a function so you can call it when you want. So the above code will run when calling the new function. Click the button 'Click Me' to run the function

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/8hc0sfbg/5/

EDIT

You wish to center the circles. I would remove any starting movements that you set, i.e when setting the cx and cy like so :

```
return 100 +  i * nodeRadius*2 + (i*difference)
```

Just get rid of the 100 which resets it. I would then translate it half of the width and remove half the width of the tens and units bounding box. Which should center it. Something like so :

```
var circleContainer = d3.select('#circleContainer')  
    var circleTensContainer = d3.select('#tens')
    var circleUnitsContainer = d3.select('#units')
var tensBBox = circleTensContainer.node().getBBox();
var unitsBBox = circleUnitsContainer.node().getBBox();
var containerSize = 40 + tensBBox.width + unitsBBox.width; 

var thisMovX = svgWidth/2 - containerSize/2; 

circleContainer.attr('transform', 'translate(' + thisMovX + ',0)' )
```

You can do something similar if you want the y centered too. I have also changed where you draw the lines too. Hope this helps :)

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/8hc0sfbg/8/

Comment: This is a much more elegant solution than mine for generating the circles - thanks for that! Only thing still needed is to get the whole thing centred horizontally - any thoughts?

Comment: @DarrellNevers Added to the answer. Apologies for the long answer, but it should help you understand a lot easier :)

Comment: I appreciate your verbosity - D3's new to me, but it seemed like the best tool for what my wife was asking. This absolutely helps - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use D3 powerful data management?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<style>
svg {
    width:480px;
    height:600px;
    margin:auto 50%;
}
circle { stroke:#ccc;stroke-width:1px;    }
.units {    fill:#09C;    }
.tens {     fill:#F00;    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var tens = [], units=[], radio=40;

for (i=0;i<Math.random()* 90 + 10;i++) tens.push(i); // [10-99]
for (i=0;i<Math.random()* 10;i++) units.push(i);     // [0-9]

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")

var units = svg.selectAll("circle.units")            // draw units
                        .data(units, function (d) {return d; })
    units.enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "units")
                .attr("cx", function (d) {return radio + Math.floor( d / 10 )*radio })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {return radio + d % 10 * radio} )
                .attr("r",  radio/2)


var tens = svg.selectAll("circle.tens")             // draw tens
                        .data(tens, function (d) {return d; })
    tens.enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "tens")
                .attr("cx", function (d) {return radio + Math.floor( d / 10 )*radio })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {return radio + d % 10 * radio} )
                .attr("r",  radio/2)
                .attr("transform","translate("+radio*2+", 0)")

svg.append('line')            //draw lines
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('y1', 480)
  .attr('x2', 80)
  .attr('y2', 480)
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 3);
svg.append('line')
  .attr('x1', 110)
  .attr('y1', 480)
  .attr('x2', 280)
  .attr('y2', 480)
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('stroke-width', 3);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here de jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50j9wv2w/